# module 'mapapi' has no attribute 'mapSetMapAccessLanguage'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть модули во внутренней библиотеке

```
import mapsyst
import maptype
import mapapi
import seekapi
```

Они нормально импортируются, но не работают ни один атрибут в стране, например:

вот код из библиотеки Mapapi

```
mapSetMapAccessLanguage_t = mapsyst.GetProcAddress(acceslib,ctypes.c_void_p,'mapSetMapAccessLanguage', ctypes.c_int)
    def mapSetMapAccessLanguage(_code: int) -> ctypes.c_void_p:
        return mapSetMapAccessLanguage_t (_code)

    mapGetMapAccessLanguage_t = mapsyst.GetProcAddress(acceslib,ctypes.c_int,'mapGetMapAccessLanguage')
    def mapGetMapAccessLanguage() -> int:
        return mapGetMapAccessLanguage_t ()
```

вот код проекта

```
mapapi.mapSetMapAccessLanguage(2)
```

(_т поставил, не в этой проблеме)

Проект не выдает ошибок, при компиляции ругается

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\GisTool14\Example\python\findobj\findobj.py", line 32, in 
mapapi.mapSetMapAccessLanguage(2)
AttributeError: module 'mapapi' has no attribute 'mapSetMapAccessLanguage'

P.S.

В VS Code появилась новая ошибка, которая лечится как то сама, тоже не понимаю, почему это, в Pycharm все работало (на VS хочу перейти, потому что он для меня удобнее)

& : Имя "C:/Users/лександр/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.7.exe" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а та
кже наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:3

- & C:/Users/лександр/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.7.exe ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/лексан...s/python3.7.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```